# no sound via HDMI using Xubuntu 13.04 32 bit AMD mesa 9.2

Tags: sound, radeon, hdmi, open-source, mesa

This question has perhaps been asked before but no clear solution seems to exist for me.  I have a Radeon 6850 connected to my screen via HDMI.  The picture is fine but I get no sound at all, not even sound effects.

This is via open source drivers.  According to [X.org Foundation](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature) website, it says HDMI audio is "Done."  I get no sound using my extra speakers with 3.5mm jack either into the motherboard itself or in the monitor.  The pavucontrol seems to recognize both the built-in sound card and HDMI card from Radeon, with the progress bar reacting to the Youtube video currently on.

Switching between built-in card and HDMI doesn't work.  Other things I've tried include downgrading to 12.10, adding the xorg-edgers ppa, manually updating the kernel to 3.9, adding the radeon.audio=1 to grub, and downloading an ALSA update from [Ubuntu Audio Development Team](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages).

The only thing that has worked is installing fglrx, but that makes my emulators crash sometimes.  Attached here is the lspci and aplay output...

```
amd-fx@amd-fx:~$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)

01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series]

amd-fx@amd-fx:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a kernel version less than 3.10.1 and you can upgrade to that or a later version, that may solve the problem.

I had the same exact problem, and after updating the kernel, my problem is gone now. (Though problems with the fan spinning all the time remain.)